# Rails5: belongs_to AND has_and_belongs_to - 2 relations between the same tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following Rails Model Relation:

```
class Grade < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many students, join_table: :grade_student_mappings
  has_many :students
end

class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :grads, join_table: :grade_student_mappings
  belongs_to :grade
end
```

Now when I want to access the grade table and the student table using the join_table - rails will fail.

Example: `Grade.find_by_id(1).student` will always response me the content of the direct relation between Grade and Student. The Relation via the join_table will be ignored.

Only when I uncomment the model line `has_many` and `belongs_to` then the indirect relation via the join_table will be considered.

How I can say to RAILS, which relation between Grade and Student I want to use ?

Answer (score 0):

Rails supports two kinds of many-to-many relationships. has_many through and has_and_belongs_to_many. You are mixing the two. You need to pick one and the more flexible one is has_many through. Change your model files to the following:

```
# app/models/grade_student_mapping.rb
belongs_to :grade
belongs_to :student

# app/models/grade.rb
has_many :grade_student_mappings, dependent: :destroy

# app/models/student.rb
has_many :grade_student_mappings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :grades, through: :grade_student_mappings
```

Then you can access the student's grades on their show template for example by setting the grades instance variable in the students_controller show action

```
# app/controllers/students_controller.rb
def show
  @grades = @student.grades
end
```

And display the grades on the student's show page. Something like the below:

```
# app/views/students/show.html.erb
<% @grades.each do |grade| %>
  <%= grade.semester %>
  <%= grade.course %>
  <%= grade.letter %>
<% end %>
```